# Help me to calculate polyhedron area or let me know the references about it.

Tags: area, polytopes

I'm a student who is studying the Management Science in the Republic of Korea.

I'm looking for a reference to calculate the area of the system of inequalities.

I can easily calculate when the number of variables is two.

But when it increases, the shape of a feasible region will have existed in high-dimensional space. so I can't calculate it.

For example, I want to calcualte the area of those three inequalities,

0.1333a + 0.0667b + 0c + (-0.2667)d >= -0.06667

0.1a + (-0.15)b + (-0.25)c + 0d>=0

(-0.025)a + 0.1b + (-0.025)c + (-0.1)d >= -0.025

**0<=a,b,c,d<=0.5**(Attached after seeing Jean Marie's reply.)

Comment: The term "area" should be replaced by hyper-volume.

Comment: There is a problem ! In the case given in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n=4$ i.e., with 4 variables, you need $n+1=5$ inequalities (instead of $3$) ; for example, in $\mathbb{R}^2$ you need (at least) 3 equations  to delimitate a triangle.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).

Answer (score 1):

What you need is hopefuly a MonteCarlo approach.

Let me explain it on your data, but with 3 variables.

Let us assume that you have the following inequations :

$$\begin{cases}
x&&&&&>&0&(\text{delimitated by plane} \ (1))\\
&&y&&&>&0&(\text{delimitated by plane} \ (2))\\
&&&&z&>&0&(\text{delimitated by plane} \ (3))\\
x&&&&&<&0.5&(\text{delimitated by plane} \ (4))\\
&&y&&&<&0.5&(\text{delimitated by plane} \ (5))\\
&&&&z&<&0.5&(\text{delimitated by plane} \ (6))\\
x&+&y&+&z&<&1&(\text{delimitated by plane} \ (7))
\end{cases}$$

The region of faisability $F$ (which is a truncated cube) has exact volume $5/48$, but instead of calculating it exactly, as I understand your purpose, you can work with approximated volumes. It suffices for that

a) to have a bounding parallelepiped B (with faces parallel to axes) for F.

b) to send $10,000$ or $100,000$ or $1,000,000$ "shoots" that either "hit the targe (feasability volume) or miss it.

c) Counting the ratio

number of points fallen in F / total number of points

is asymptoticaly like computing vol(F)/vol(B).

In the case described by inequalities (1), one would write a (Matlab) program like this :

```
n=100000;
c=0;
V0=1/8;
for k=1:n
    x=0.5*rand;y=0.5*rand;z=0.5*rand;
    if x+y+z<1 % constraint (7)
        c=c+1; % target hitted : increase count 
    end;
end;
V=(c/n)*V0; %according to relationship V/V0=c/n
```

(recall : rand = uniformly distributed pseudo-random result on $[0,1]$ ; in this way, constraints (1) to (6) are naturally fulfilled).
Running this program, one gets a result around 1.04, very close to the exact one $5/48$. If you want to increase average precision, just take a bigger $n$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My interest is, "are there any ways to find the polyhedron area or volume only using those 3 equations(To tell the truth, there are two additional information all variables(a,b,c,d)>=0 and variables(a,b,c,d)<=0.5, but I  thoutght those informations are not important). ars there any methods for the volume or the surface area using only those information?

Comment: Information $(a,b,c,d)\leq 0.5$ cannot be guessed. It is, for sure, important. Another thing : why are you looking for the (hyper)volume of the so called "feasible set" (vocabulary of the domain called "linear programming")  ? It is the first time I see that it could be interesting... Could you say what usage you intend for this volume ?

Comment: I want to find the volumes for comparing the alternatives' dominance. For example, if there are three alternatives values like Alt1=1a+2b+3c, Alt2=2a+2b+2c, Alt3=3a+2b+2c, then I hope to find the area based on each of alternatives dominance areas, which are obtained from those three equations. 1.Alt1-Alt2, Alt1-Alt3; 2. Alt2-Alt1, Alt2-Alt3; 3.Alt3-Alt1, Alt3-Alt2.

Comment: I understand. I have made up my mind about your issue : hopefully, what you need is to use a MonteCarlo simulation for an **approximate computation** of the (hyper)-volume. If I have time, I will develop the idea as an Edit to my answer.

Comment: I have completely re-written my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot about your kind answers. I'll try by using your method.
I can understand all the sentences except the V0 in line 3. Is there any reason for setting the V0=1/8?

Comment: @김종현 After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, please [consider "accept" the answer](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4945/290189) by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](//math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: I took Vo=1/8 because it is the volume of the bounding box $[0,1/2] \times [0,1/2] \times [0,1/2]$ of the polyhedron.